# Converting a list of integers to a tuple of lists

Tags: list, f#, tuples

I'm trying to convert a list of integers to a tuple of lists in a recursive function.

Let's say I have a list of integers as `[1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8]` and I want to turn this into `([1;3;5;7],[2;4;6;8])` dividing odds and evens on different sides

I'm facing with a lot of problems such as expected result being `'a list * 'a list` and I'm having a `'b * 'c` even tho `'b & 'c` are lists of integers.

Comment: Can you show us the code you have had so far?

Comment: Well the code I have is different and a partion of something else but I can write an examplary code;

let rec oddEven lst
    match lst with
    [] -> ([],[])
    |x::xs -> if (x % 2 = 0) then ...
              else if (x % 2 > 0) then ...;;

I'm new to f# and I'm kinda stuck right now.

Comment: Your code fragment isn't complete and doesn't show the problem you're facing. Please consider to add a complete and helpful example.

Answer (score 6):

Since you asked specifically for a recursive function..:

```
let partitionNumbers nums =
    let rec impl odds evens = function
      | []                   -> odds, evens
      | n::ns when n % 2 = 1 -> impl (n::odds) evens ns
      | n::ns                -> impl odds (n::evens) ns
    List.rev nums |> impl [] []
```

However the more idiomatic approach is (as *almost*-always) to use higher-order functions:

```
let partitionNumbers = List.partition (fun n -> n % 2 = 1)
```